# How to include editable component data into static non-Sitecore component?

Tags: jss

I have a footer that I want to include by default into the layout rather than be injected as a Sitecore component by a content editor. The footer data, however, should be editable and translatable. Is there any way to achieve this?

*SiteFooter.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-react';
import SiteFooterLink from '../SiteFooterLink';

const SiteFooter = ({ fields }) => (
    <footer id="site-footer" className="site-footer">
        <div className="container container--content container--med container--centred">
            <div className="site-footer__links">
                { fields.links.map((item, index) => (
                    <SiteFooterLink key={index} {...item} />
                )) }
            </div>

            <div className="site-footer__copyright">
                <p className="copy copy--sml copy--faded copy--flush"><Text field={fields.copyrightCopy} /> {(new Date()).getFullYear()}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
);

export default SiteFooter;
```

*SiteFooterLink.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-react';

const SiteFooterLink = ({ fields }) =>
  Object.keys(fields).length ?
    <div className="site-footer__link">
      <Link field={fields.attributes} className="link" />
    </div>
    : null;

export default SiteFooterLink;
```

The following is my `component-content` data file.

*en.yml*

```
id: site-footer
name: Site Footer
componentName: SiteFooter
fields:
  copyrightCopy: © Company
  links:
  - id: site-footer-link-1
  - id: site-footer-link-2
  - id: site-footer-link-3
  - id: site-footer-link-4
  - id: site-footer-link-5
  - id: site-footer-link-6
```

To summarise, I want to:

- Include the footer component directly into the layout.
- Import/link the `component-content` data to the footer.
- Update the data (translations, links) based on the current language.

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't have a statically component and have it access data from the layout. There are ways to make it work though that would require you to change your approach slightly:

1. Connect the footer to an app-level placeholder. This may look wrong in disconnected, but once you integrate with Sitecore, you can migrate the footer placement to the `__Standard Values` of the base template, so you can have the placement inherited across the board. This would mean you need a base template for all of your pages.
2. Move the footer data into Layout Service context. So instead of the fields being a part of the fields on an item, you have a "resolver" that returns the footer links as a part of the `context` object:
   https://jss.sitecore.net/docs/techniques/extending-layout-service/layoutservice-extending-context#extending-context-data-returned-by-the-layout-service

   This is fine for smaller payloads, but not great for "mega navs" as the payload will travel with each page request.
3. Have the footer make a connected GraphQL request for footer links. This is another call to the server, but you can cache it with GraphQL client like Apollo.
   See more here: https://jss.sitecore.net/docs/techniques/graphql/connected-graphql#connected-graphql-in-jss-apps

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Dictionary Service](http://jss.sitecore.net/docs/fundamentals/services/dictionary-service) and [Dictionary Import](https://jss.sitecore.net/docs/techniques/content-translation#translation-of-dictionary-items). Content that's not in a component really only has one place to go, and that's the Dictionary. You could use other services as well (SSC or GraphQL) but that would require working Sitecore-first.

Comment: not really an answer, rather references to what might eventually be an answer